# SQL Server: Getting duplicate results for results that match my WHERE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

There's probably a very easy resolution to this, but I just can't see it. I don't have the exact query with me, but I broke it down as much as I could and gave a very close example of my final SELECT statement and an example of the issue with my results. 
What I'm trying to do:
I'm grabbing a handful of different documents in my query, which is no problem because I'm using a:

```
WHERE d.document IN ('Document 1', 'Document 2', 'Document 3', 'Document 4')
```

This is working fine. It's pulling those documents into a field, which is what I need.

The trouble is I need specific information about one of those Documents. I need to know if a question was used in Document 4. And if it was, I need to list the answer to those questions in a separate column. The Questions is one table and the Answers is another table.

So I'm putting all my other data (most not mentioned and irrelevant to this problem) into temp tables for performance. When I get to the final SELECT statement, using my #finaltemp table, I'm trying to add the field that will provide the answer for Document 4. I'm doing something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
t.*,
CASE
     WHEN t.Question = 'question 17' THEN t.answer
     ELSE NULL
END AS "Doc5Ans"
FROM #temp t
```

The desired results would have all of my basic data field, which it does, but also have an additional field that will give the answer to the question from Document 5. Obviously, all the other Documents are going to receive a NULL value in this field, which is what I want.

The problem is: whenever I have a Document 5 with a match (the question's answer), I'll get a perfect row with the data I'm looking for, BUT I'm also getting a duplicate row with a NULL value (instead of the answer). So for every time there's a row with a Document 5 answer, there's another row with all of the same information, except the field in question has NULL.

For whatever reason, whenever I have a match, it's giving me a row with the correct data and a row with a NULL. It's always being accounted for twice. I only want NULLs for the other documents that don't have nor need that, and that's working fine, but why am I getting an additional NULL row for a result that has match?

```
ID        Name.       DocName     Doc5Ans
321421    Person 1    DocOne       NULL
342611    Person 2    DocOne       NULL
373916    Person 3    DocThree     NULL
377625    Person 4    DocFive      Answer1
377625    Person 4    DocFive      NULL
```

The last two rows is an example of what I'm talking about. 
It shouldn't be giving me a NULL for Person 4. SQL is somehow adding my value, but also adding a row with NULL when Doc5Answer meets the criteria. 
What's going on with this? 
Thanks for taking the time to read and help.

Comment: Please show clear sample data, your current output, and your expected output.  This question is not clear in my opinion.

Comment: I added my sample data and the output I'm getting in the post. My desired result is not having the last row of the sample results table I posted. Unfortunately I don't have the exact query with me, but this example I posted is the part of the query where the issue begins.

Comment: Please show us the `t.Question` value in each case.

Comment: Let's say you have two entries in #temp for DocFive. For one the question is "question 69" and for the other the question is "question 17". In this case, you'd have _one distinct line for each:_ for DocFive with the answer to question 17 _AND_ DocFive with null. One way around this is a proper group by statement with case aggregation. For example, `SELECT ID, Name, DocName, Doc5Ans = MAX(CASE WHEN Question = 'Question 17' THEN Answer END) FROM #temp GROUP BY ID, Name, DocName;`